App Context en una variable global
estoy teniendo un tema para poder obtener el application context en una clase que no se hereda de nada, es decir en un interceptor de retrofit.
requiero obtener datos de room en el interceptor para poder obtener me jwt que esta en la base de datos pero para eso requiero ponerle el application context, no lo puedo inyectar por constructor ya que viene de un objeto retrofit, me gustaría saber si hay manera de crear una constante o variable publica con ese dato (app cpntext) para solo llamarlo , es posible? o que me recomiendan?
gracias

Agrega el código que estas realizando para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte de una mejor forma.

Para obtener el contexto de manera "global", crea una crea una clase que extienda de la clase Application :
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context

class MyApp : Application() {

    init {
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
    
        private var instance: MyApp? = null

        fun applicationContext(): Context {
            return instance!!.applicationContext
        }

    }
}

Dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml en "application" define esta clase, especificando el paquete donde se encuentra
<application
    android:name="com.mypackage.MyApplicationContext"

ahora para obtener el contexto en tus demás clases este es un ejemplo:
 var context = MyApp.applicationContext()

